# Gradle Multiproject

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to configure gradle for a multiproject environment.

My project structure is as follows:

```
MainProject
--external
  --A
  --B
  --C
```

I have been able to configure the build.gradle and the settings.gradle file for the MainProject.

The problem that I have is that both subprojects A & B depend on C

In project A 's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project('../C')
}
```

Gradle says unable to find project with path ../C. What path should I put in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
compile project(':external:C')
```

For more details about project paths see [section 56.5](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec%3aproject_and_task_paths) in the Gradle user guide.

Comment: Initially the path specified was the same as what you are suggesting. It was generated by eclipse adt plugin. However gradle gave an error, unable to find project. After reading the article, shouldn't the path be :external:C as colon itself denotes root project?