# Sharing class path configuration between multiple gradle subprojects

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle

I have two different java projects, projectA and projectB. I'm at a stage where projectB depends on projectA. How do I pull in the jars created by building projectA and all of its dependencies?

In essence, I would like to mirror the effect of adding a projectA to the build path of projectB in eclipse,effectively pulling in jars on the classpath projectA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle Multiproject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746402/gradle-multiproject)

Comment: It's a different question. The other user is asking how to get a path

Answer (score 2):

1. If the two projects are closely related you can make Project A and Project B part of the same Multi-project build, then:

   ```
   //ProjectB build.gradle
   dependencies {
     compile project(':ProjectA')
   }
   ```
2. If they're not closely related you can [publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) the output of Project A to a repository e.g. your local Maven, [Artificatory](http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/), [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) etc. Then in Project B you'll get it like any other dependency. E.g.

   ```
   //ProjectB build.gradle
   repositories {
     mavenLocal()
     //Or something like this:
     //maven { url "http://urltoyourartifactory.com/repo/" }
   }

   dependencies {
     compile 'com.yourname:project-a:1.0.0'
   }
   ```

Comment: Do I get project-a jar and all of it's dependencies by doing this or am I just getting project-a jar?

Comment: If Project A is setup correctly, all it's dependencies will be included by default. To manage which transitive dependencies are added from Project A into Project B, have a look at the [Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) chapter

Comment: I have this setup but when I store a file in `core/src/main/resources/item.txt` then my web project can't use Spring's `ResourceLoader.getResource("classpath:item.txt")` and vice versa.

If the file is stored in `web/src/main/resoures/item.txt` then my core project can't use Spring's `ResourceLoader.getResource("classpath:item.txt")` command.

The error is always `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

My `build.gradle` for web is such that is says `compile project(':core')`. Any ideas?

Comment: @anon sounds like you may need to read the content from the classpath as an InputStream and not as a file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876836/file-inside-jar-is-not-visible-for-spring

Comment: @HeinrichFilter thanks for the input but that didn't solve the problem. No method of importing the file through Spring's `ResourceLoader`, `ClassLoader`, as a file, or as an input stream helped the issue.

What I had to do was 'import' the core's project resources folder at build time for the 'web' project in the build.gradle file. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686346/584947